# I'm using kali: Wireless adapter detects available networks but won't connect to any

Tags: kali-linux, wireless-adapter

It says it's down and I can't get it up. What do i do?

This is the data I have gathered:

```
kali@kali:~$ ip a show wlan0
3: wlan0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 
1000 link/ether ...

kali@kali:~$ sudo lsusb | grep Real
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:818b Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8192EU 802.11b/g/n WLAN Adapter

kali@kali:~$ sudo iwconfig wlan0
wlan0     IEEE 802.11  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr=2347 B   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:off
```

I have tried:

```
kali@kali:~$ sudo ifconfig wlan0 up
kali@kali:~$ sudo ifup -a
kali@kali:~$ ip link set  up
```

I had the adapter in monitor mode a while if that helps:

```
kali@kali:~$ dmesg  
[  113.684001] usb 1-2: RTL8192EU rev B (SMIC) 2T2R, TX queues 3, WiFi=1, BT=0, GPS=0, HI PA=0
[  113.684002] usb 1-2: RTL8192EU MAC: xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
[  113.684003] usb 1-2: rtl8xxxu: Loading firmware rtlwifi/rtl8192eu_nic.bin
[  113.686259] usb 1-2: firmware: direct-loading firmware rtlwifi/rtl8192eu_nic.bin
[  113.686269] usb 1-2: Firmware revision 19.0 (signature 0x92e1)

[  225.950299] wlan0: authenticate with xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
[  225.983915] wlan0: send auth to xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx (try 1/3)
[  226.189124] wlan0: send auth to xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx (try 2/3)
[  226.391996] wlan0: send auth to xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx (try 3/3)
[  226.600525] wlan0: authentication with xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx timed out
```

Comment: I can't help any with rtlwifi, but don't confuse two different things: you're changing the master switch (`ip link set`) but you're looking at the operational state (NO-CARRIER). "Powered on" does not necessarily mean "connected".

Comment: Thank you. Will take a look into it then, didn't know the difference so will keep that in mind :)